# Flutter Doctor (Incorrectly?) Reporting Android Studio Flutter Plugin Not Installed

Tags: android-studio, flutter

When I ran flutter doctor it reports that my Android Studio Flutter and Dart plugins are not installed, even though I have the latest installed - and in fact, I can build and deploy a flutter app to a mobile device from Android Studio. I think either my config somewhere isn't correct or flutter doctor has a bug.

When I run `flutter doctor -v` I get the following:

```
d:\Dev\Flutter>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.8-pre.264, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 0.5.8-pre.264 at D:\Dev\Flutter\Flutter
    • Framework revision b32c77a012 (12 hours ago), 2018-08-07 17:09:14 -0700
    • Engine revision 7f083e54fe
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.69.5.flutter-b04def964c

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: d:\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at d:\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • android-studio-dir = d:\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • HTC PN071 • HT485W903981 • android-arm • Android 5.0.2 (API 21)

• No issues found!
```

I am running Windows 10 using Android Studio 3.1.4. I have switched flutter git branch to master. I have tried uninstall and reinstall the plugins but no success so far.

Below is my Android Studio plugin screenshot:

[image]

Comment: There's [this github thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11940) that might be worth following. Moreover, [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11940#issuecomment-406203746) might be a more thorough explanation Hope it helps...

Comment: It's simple just try reinstalling your flutter sdk

Comment: @Baksman I tried that already, but might give it a try again.

Comment: `'flutter doctor'` only check android studio plugin whether it is in dorectory `'${yourUserHome}/.AndroidStudioX.Y/config/plugins'`. And the directory `'${yourUserHome}/.AndroidStudioX.Y'` could not be a link. I guess your directory `'${yourUserHome}/.AndroidStudioX.Y'` is a soft link made by `'mklink /D'` because I do this before and met your problems.

Comment: This one worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529134/1492681

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
Settings > languages and frameworks > flutter
```

And then on the sdk path browse the directory where you have downloaded flutter. And check to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using the conventional C: drive. Make sure you do not have another version of android studio installed on your system. This would lead flutter to detect a different version without the flutter plugin.

If there is no duplicate installed, there may just be residual files (ie: a backup).

This is just a guess but I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else ran into this issue, it turns out that my channel was on 'stable' (1.22.1), switching to 'dev' solved the problem. This is a issue, will certanily been fixed in future 'stable' releases.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBSXC.png)

Answer (score -1):

in case mine i have both android studio and intellij idea installed on my system so i uninstalled intellij idea that fixed my problem

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an issue. Just ignore it. I also only use vscode and get this "issue". Maybe it would be good changing that issue to a info or warning because it could unsettle new flutter developers.