# Flutter plugin not installed error; When running 'flutter doctor'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-doctor

I am configuring the Flutter SDK on my Linux [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) system. Why am I getting the following error when I run the flutter doctor?

I have specified both `PATHS` for `flutter` and `dart` in the `.bashrc` file, but I get this error when I run `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
[!] VS Code (version 1.25.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: I think you just need to update to a newer Flutter version.

Comment: **On Windows > Android Studio > File > Settings > Plugins > Search for flutter > Install**

Comment: You can ignore that if you;re not using Android Studio in Flutter Development. By default, Flutter and Dart plugins are not installed in Android Studio. You still need to manually install them. 

I would recommend VSCode in flutter development since it's lightweight.

Comment: In my case I had projects with different gradle versions. So in **gradle-wrapper.properties** I set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`
and in **build.gradle** 
 `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }`

Comment: But not required if you use Visual Studio Code I think.

Comment: all of the solutions do not work for me. Notice, I installed flutter and dart plugin already. How can I resolve the problem ?

Comment: Please answer these two questions. 
I am stuck here.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338060/flutter-screen-recording-dialog-press
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338362/flutter-share-video-on-youtube-using-sharing-intent

Comment: This happens when flutter doctor cannot find the Android Studio plugins. It's an issue between flutter version and Android Studio version. For example, Android Studio 4.1 stores the plugins in ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1, and obviously flutter doesn't know about this and most probably looks in some old location that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I get same problem, any best solution please

Comment: here is my answer please give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/64962784/12553303

Comment: flutter upgrade worked for me

Answer (score 428):

Safe fix for Mac (Android Studio 4.1+). It is in a different directory now, but the symbolic link helps.

Just run this command in the Terminal:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

If you have a different Android Studio version or an installation folder, adjust the command accordingly.

Comment: hi brother, this work for me , can more explain for what this command do ?

Comment: @q8yas Command just redirects flutter doctor to the different folder to find plugins (where they are now)

Comment: This did not work for me, however, installing the plugin manually via the Android Studio, like Paresh Mangukiya recommended, did work.

Comment: This worked for me. Already installed the plugin. But same error was repeating. But this worked perfectly.

Comment: I have the same problem. How do I fix this on windows 10?

Comment: WFM - Android Studio 4.1, Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G4032 darwin-x64, locale en-GB) - thanks!

Comment: didn't work for me with Android Studio 4.2b4 as of February 13, 2021

Comment: @BNetz you should check your android studio 4.2 path and update the given command with according path.

Comment: So the second path is exact like the first one just one directory-level higher?

Comment: Because I seem to come back here every month or so... this is the command for Arctic Fox that worked for me: `ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio2020.3`

Answer (score 106):

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available
```

*A solution that worked for me*:

1. Just install plugins.
   Android Studio → menu *File* → *Settings* → *Plugins* → *Browse Repositories*
2. Search for "flutter".
3. Tap on *Install* (a dialog will pop regarding the Dart dependency. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd>).
4. Once the installation is finished **restart** Android Studio.

[image]

*Now run `flutter doctor`:*

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available
```

[android](/questions/tagged/android)[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[flutter-doctor](/questions/tagged/flutter-doctor)

Comment: I installed flutter and dart plugin already. it does not work :(. I use android studio 3.1

Comment: @MrSpecial Did you installed Android studio in different path? I have the same issue. My installation path is different and plugin is stored in User path

Comment: @noobEinstien How did you fix then?

Comment: @Atul didn't fixed, They just showing available editors, it is not really matters.

Answer (score 90):

I had the same issue and none of the above answers fixed it, so I went to the Flutter official GitHub repository and found the answer there. Here is the link and you have to follow all these steps.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986

**Flutter upgrade**

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

For Mac, you can do the following as [answered by Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor/64529134#64529134):

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1

flutter doctor -v
```

Then if the issue still persists then just shift to the beta channel and upgrade Flutter. Then it will fix it.

**Flutter channel beta**

**Flutter upgrade**

You can enable [Flutter web](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) as an optional step.

Comment: This worked on Windows 10, Flutter Beta and Android Studio 4.1.1. Thanks!

Comment: Had this problem with stable Flutter (1.22.6) and Android Studio 4.1.2, and switching Flutter to the beta channel (1.26.0-17.6.pre) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 53):

For those who still have this error, even if they have tried the solutions mentioned before, try this. It works on Windows 10, macOS, and Linux (run in the command line):

1. `flutter channel dev`
2. `flutter upgrade`
3. `flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

Comment: Switching to dev channel does seam to work on linux, too. Thanks for the tipp!

Comment: It works perfectly on Windows 10. Thanks !!

Comment: a happy user from Mac too!

Comment: Thaaaaaanks <3 Worked for me on Win 10

Answer (score 41):

**The issue is just that "flutter doctor" is not able to read behind the scene that everything is fine and up to date.
This issue is temporary (till next patch or update) and can be avoided as it won't affect anywhere in the development process.**

This is a frequently occurring issue when we are updating a newer version of Flutter.
Recently also upon updating to Flutter 1.22.1(Stable), it throws a "Plugins Not installed" error, while they are installed and up to date.
Uninstalling and reinstalling will also not work as Android Studio will again pick the same version to install.

Comment: So this has just occurred in the new release? did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Yes occurred this time also. It's better to ignore it. It is only a health report of our setup and should not be manipulated. It is in the knowledge of team flutter by now.

Comment: Its a bug, my android studio runs flutter properly just doesn't show on ```flutter doctor -v``` . I am opening an issue on Github to notify the devs, hopefully it will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: Still an issue in Flutter 1.22.5 (Stable)

Comment: Still an issue in Flutter 1.22.6 (Stable)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It can't be understood why this left pending by the Flutter team. There are some other such small bugs that have been reported to the developers and have been taken into account but haven't been solved. Funny thing is that the beta versions are free from few of these bugs (haven't tested the latest one though).

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue, but I fixed it just after running these commands:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
```

Comment: It is interesting how this helped to fix the issue! Helped me. Thanks for posting.

Comment: What is this sorcery? +1

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 20.04!

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem when having multiple versions of **Android Studio**, and it doesn't look like you have multiple versions. But you do use **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition**, so are you sure you did install the plugins in **Android Studio**?

Answer (score 12):

According to following images first install required Flutter and Dart plugins and then after downloading the Flutter SDK from [official-flutter-sdk-download-page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows), add Flutter and Dart paths:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with installing the required Flutter and Dart plugins. There are two ways in which you can achieve this:

1. Go to Android studio → Settings → plugins → in the search bar search for Flutter and Dart plugins.
   If you are installing Flutter first, then Dart may get automatically installed along with it; otherwise install them separately.
2. If you are using Visual Studio Code, in the activity bar click on extensions or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. There you can search for Flutter and Dart plugins.

Now type `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 10):

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and Android Studio were installed on my machine. I deleted IntelliJ IDEA, because I have installed the Dart and Flutter plugins in Android Studio. Then the `flutter doctor` command works perfectly.

Comment: I've faced with this problem before when I was developing Android app both in `Android studio` and `Intellij Idea` at the same time. Both of them was writing to the same folder in the local path. It maybe the same issue here as well.

Answer (score 9):

**Linux users:** I `cd`'d into my home directory, added
 `export PATH="$PATH:/home/frodo/flutter/bin/flutter"` in the `.bashrc` file, and `source`ed it to refresh the `.bashrc` file. It depends on where you moved your Flutter SDK.

Then I run `flutter doctor`. I got the following results:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
[!] VS Code (version 1.25.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available
```

To export the Flutter path permanently:

`export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/dir"` in the `.bashrc` file

For example:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/frodo/flutter/bin/flutter"
```

And run:

```
source .bashrc
```

[**How to permanently set `$PATH` on Linux/Unix**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Answer (score 8):

When you execute the `flutter doctor` command it checks your environment and displays a report to the terminal window. In your case it seems that you did not install the Dart and Flutter plugin to be able to use them in Android Studio.

To install a plugin, click on menu *File* → *Settings* → *Plugins* → Install JetBrains plugins

The plugins will add new functionalities to Android Studio related to Flutter. Example: it will add the Flutter inspector, outliner.

The SDK that you added to the path will be needed when creating a new Flutter project.

[image]

Comment: I already installed dart and their paths to `.bashrc`. When I type `flutter` or `dart` in the terminal. The command line shows me a list of commands to use for either `dart` or `flutter`.

Comment: yes but u need to also install the flutter and dart plugins for android studio to be able to use their functionality inside android studio. When you install the flutter plugin for android studio and click file>new you will have a new option called "new flutter project"

Answer (score 7):

You missed [this step](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio) in the installation process.

Install the Flutter and Dart plugins:

- Start Android Studio.
- Open plugin preferences (File → Settings → Plugins on **Windows & Linux** OR Preferences → Plugins on **macOS**).
- Select <kbd>Browse repositories</kbd>, select the Flutter plugin and click <kbd>Install</kbd>.
- Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
- Click <kbd>Restart</kbd> when prompted.

If are using Visual Studio Code, to install the Flutter and Dart plugins:

- Start Visual Studio Code.
- Invoke View → Command Palette.
- Type `install`, and select <kbd>Extensions: Install Extensions</kbd>.
- Type `flutter` in the extensions search field, select <kbd>Flutter</kbd> in the list, and click <kbd>Install</kbd>. This also installs the required Dart plugin.
- Validate your setup with the Flutter Doctor
- Invoke View → Command Palette….
- Type `doctor`, and select the Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor.

Review the output in the OUTPUT pane for any issues.

Answer (score 6):

I met a similar error after updating Android Studio, and it turns out I need to update the existing Flutter plugin.

To fix it, go to Android Studio → Preferences → Plugins → Installed → update your installed Flutter plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to install it on Windows

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

1. Open Android Studio, menu *File* → *Settings* → *Plugins* and *make sure* you have Flutter and Dart installed

   [image]
2. Go to Visual Studio Code to *Extensions* and install the Flutter and Dart extensions

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by opening the plugin in settings, where under the 'installed' tab, I noticed the blue text 'Plugin homepage' which was  a shortcut to the JetBrains plugins. There was an agreement which I had to accept to get the full functionality. I did accept and I also edited my environment variables by adding path to the bin of dart-SDK. Previously I only had the bin of flutter added to path. Anyway, this solved my problem.

Comment: Accepting the agreement did the trick for me, thank you!

Comment: What environment variable (name)? `PATH`? Or another one?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986#issuecomment-707881534), the plugins warnings doesn't matter. At least it didn't matter for me, and it's worked fine.

As stated,

> hi @EastCartel, try with flutter config
> --android-studio-dir=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio or your correct path. and you have 3 issues.
>
> 1- First open your android studio and add the flutter plugin (this
> automaticly add dart plugin too).
>
> [image]
>
> 2- Also open visual studio code and add flutter extension.
>
> [image]
>
> 3- And run flutter doctor --android-licenses
>
> [image]
>
> if the problem persist try flutter upgrade
>
> good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just update Flutter SDK using

> flutter upgrade

It solved my all issues.

```
Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code then navigate to extensions and search for Flutter. Then simply install it and you must take care that you have already installed Dart there.

After that, if it doesn't work, then copy your Flutter bin path that you can locate at C/'flutter-SDK-path'/bin. Then copy it and add it to the environment variable and add it to that path, so you can easily be able to access Flutter.

If you are using Android Studio then the already-stated article help you.

And make sure that you have latest versions of SDKs and Android Studio or Visual Studio Code. So that versions can't introduce any error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only VSCode for development then you don't need to install plugins for Android Studio and vice versa. It will never give you a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by uninstalling Flutter from the Plugins. After restarting Android Studio, I opened the plugins, and then it shows that my Dart plugin is not compatible with my Android Studio (v3.6).

I updated Dart, restarted Android Studio, and then reinstalled Flutter again. After that, I have to set the SDK path for the Flutter and voilà everything works now :D

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just had this problem after an update and I solved it entering menu *File* → *Settings* → *Plugins*. Then at the top of the window there are two options: *Marketplace* and *Installed*. Then I clicked on *Installed* and on the Flutter plugin there’s was a message saying that the current version of Flutter does not support the new version of Android Studio, so there was a green button written “Restart”. Then I clicked and when it opened again, the problem disappeared.

It may not be the same for you, but many people will search for it here and it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in **Terminal**:

```
flutter config --android-sdk C:\Users\CHAMOD\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Then **restart the IDE**.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing these issues and found these solutions.

You've to install both "Flutter" and "Dart" plugins from MarketPlace.

For Windows: Android Studio → menu *File* → *Settings* → *Plugins* → search for "flutter" and "dart" and install them. Make sure you got this.

> [image: You may be needed to update them]
>
> **Now make sure you have set the SDK paths for both** [image: SDK path for Dart] [image: SDK path for Flutter]
>
> **Now enjoy the fresh Flutter** [image]

Oh, you can upgrade to a new version just by typing `flutter upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and can not fix by myself.

However, by using Visual Studio Code, it works fine. That error does *not* matter.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed Android Studio more than one time, the command prompt or PowerShell assigned on the first one and maybe you are running the second one. So, browse for Android Studio, if you have more than one installation, delete the first one. Then, download the Plugins in Android Studio by following theese steps.

**Step 1**:Studio --> File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Browse Repositories

**Step 2**: Search for **Flutter** and **download it**

**Step 3**: When you're done **restart** Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install **Flutter** and **Dart** both on Visual Studio Code as well as Android Studio!

Try using the following command:

**flutter doctor --android-licenses**, and press y to install all licenses.

[image: result]

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem a few days back. Here's what worked for me,

1. Run the following commands

   ```
   flutter channel beta
   flutter upgrade
   flutter config --enable-web
   ```

   The snippet's main purpose is to enable web support for Flutter, but it also changes the release channel and updates the Flutter SDK to the latest version.
2. Run `flutter doctor` again; hopefully, it wouldn't show any issues now

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I wasn't able to enable the plugin because I've recently updated to version **4.2.2** in Android Studio and I've checked out a *Flutter SDK version* which was *not a stable version.*

After I changed to a stable version while using **fvm** and re-install the plugin, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Final i resolved this issue to run below command.
I am using android 4.2 and OS is Mac

> ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/plugins
> ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.2