# disabled Run and loading button in android Studio

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I reset my pc and installed android studio again there wasn't any problem but when I created a new flutter project I noticed that the 'run' button 'loading device' button was disabled on their own. i have to run my program from the terminal as nothing is working.
I have tried upgrading Gradle and running the android studio as an administrator but nothing works.
any help would be appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you restart your PC after the installation of Android Studio?

Comment: yes, I did that after installation.

Comment: I followed this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395106/update-to-android-studio-4-1-flutter-plugin-and-dart-plugin-not-installed/64481789#64481789) as i was facing the same problem and changed 'stable' to 'dev' channel. but reversing does no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the path on `android studio SDK and NDK` and `emulator SDK` again to your `system PATH` variable

this might help [Flutter does not find android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk?rq=1)