# Android Studio Flutter errors after updating

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-doctor

Yesterday I updated flutter from the command line. Then dart as well (I was prompted). After that all of my classes that have String in them appear to have errors (String isn't a type -of course I do import dart-core but nothing happens).

[image]

Flutter doctor gives this error

[image]

event though they seem to be installed

[image]

I 've seen the following but nothing helps

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28995

[Flutter plugin not installed error;. When running flutter doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor/52816669#52816669)

[Android Studio flutter and dart plugins not recognized by flutter doctor , but plugins are installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336654/android-studio-flutter-and-dart-plugins-not-recognized-by-flutter-doctor-but-p?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I 'm on stable channel, Android Studio 4.1. I have tried everything found in here (flutter pub get, upgrade, clean etc, Android Studio's invalidate cache, but still the same. I can work from the command line, but that is not a solution.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably need to update the Dart SDK Path in Android Studio. I am in IntelliJ with the Dart plugin, and for me the path is set at `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Dart`. On Mac, it should be at `/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec`.

Comment: You do not need to set Dart SDK path when you are developing Flutter apps. Setting Dart SDK path is for developing Dart-only applications (command line, etc.). I would avoid doing that to prevent making the problem more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

go to setting
and check your dart sdk path.
[image]

after set or check your path.
if its wrong. set right path and then
Enable dart support module for your project.
after this click on apply.

Comment: It was the flutter sdk path that was empty, but you pointed me to the right direction. Thank you very much Shirsh!