# Flutter Screen Recording Dialog Press

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, screen-recording

How can I detect which button is pressed "start now" or "cancel" to change some design by pressing them. The dialog open by this line of code,

```
FlutterScreenRecording.startRecordScreen("file.mp4");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have some boolen variable in your state. and on click of start now call setState function as below :

```
setState(() {
   startRecording = true;
})
```

where you want to show changes check whether it has become true or not. On true do the changes otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: is there any callBack method for onClick of start now and cancel?

Comment: yes you can set on press for both of them separetely for start now a different function will be called and for cancel most likely you will pop of the dialog box.

Comment: Can you please send me those callBack methods ?

Comment: @ZeeshanFareed you can check the example here https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-video-capture-example for complete recording