# Flutter share video on youtube using sharing intent

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, file-sharing, android-sharing

When press on share button It opens the sharing dialog box as shown below, 
[image]

When press on youtube it share video on youtube as shown below,
[image]

The thing I want is that by pressing share button it get video from DCIM and it does not open the sharing dialog like image-1 but directly open the youtube by default like image-2 to share video on youtube. I want this in flutter.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to do that?

Comment: No, I think flutter developer are not that expert to answer all type of questions.