# Failed on build on Flutter App "task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the standard flutter app on Android Studio and when I can't execute flutter pub get and when I execute flutter run I get this exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        18,2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already try force upgrade and flutter clean

**Flutter Doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Windows, locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.17.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (4 days ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 540786dd51
    • Dart version 2.8.1


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\kaduc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\kaduc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I already uninstall Android Studio IDE and reinstall and I try reinstalling Java JDK but don't chance anything don't know what can I do to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try flutter clean?

Comment: try `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` /debug your project.make sure you're connected to the internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**
Either flutter and dart plugins are not download properly or not configured properly with Android Studio.
**Solution:**
There is a way to fix this. You can just install/reinstall the Flutter & Dart plugin in android studio by steps below.
1) Open the Android Studio.
2) Open plugin preferences (File > Settings > Plugins on "Windows" & "Linux" or Preferences > Plugins on "macOS").
3) Select Browse repositories, select the Flutter plug-in and click install.
4) Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
5) Click Restart when prompted.
6) Run command: `sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME YOUR_FLUTTER_DIRECTORY`
Example: `sudo chown -R sanketvekariya /opt/flutter`
**Some References:**
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21881 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45528 
[Flutter plugin not installed error;. When running flutter doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor) 
**FYI:**
I have faced same issue earlier and solved by above steps. Hope you solve this soon.:)

Comment: Ty man Actually my Android Studio was on offline mode and I couldn't get the plugin but your answer show me where to look for problems.

Comment: your welcome! You can also upvote the answer along with accepting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I delete the \android\app\build folder, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I cloned the project from repo and project was developed by my colleague months ago. So I solved the issue by updating gradle version in **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and also updating `tools.build:gradle` in **android/build.gradle** file.