# FLUTTER ALREADY INSTALLED! but still shows "Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality"

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

**FLUTTER and DART ALREADY INSTALLED! but still shows "Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality"**

```
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
```

Appreciate your helps.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @NabeelParkar: How about Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in the command line

ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1

... it worked for me... sorry I have no explanation , I got it from this link in stack overflow ...

[Flutter plugin not installed error;. When running flutter doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor) (answer 40)! hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands:

step 1 : `run> flutter channel dev`
step 2 : `run> flutter channel updrade`
step 3 : `run > flutter config --android-studio-dir="E:\Android Studio"`

at step2
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> flutter channel upgrade
Switching to flutter channel 'upgrade'...
This is not an official channel. For a list of available channels, try "flutter channel".
git: fatal: 'origin/upgrade' is not a commit and a branch 'upgrade' cannot be created from it
Switching channels failed with error code 128.

but it doesn't matter
when i try  “flutter doctor” ，there are no issues.

thanks