# Android Studio Dart And Flutter Plugin is not installed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Here is the `flutter doctor` result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I have already installed the `flutter` plugin. But the problem still exists. How can I fix this?

Comment: Relevant bug report on flutter issues: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37670

Answer (score 33):

Just run this on your terminal (Mac users)

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Comment: The sensible solution here!

Comment: Out of so many suggestions about this problem on the Internet, this is the ONLY thing that works for me.

Comment: Thank you you save my day and  for Android Studio 4.2 
 ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.2

Answer (score 30):

Well hello all

I would suggest you all to follow the steps what flutter documentation sites tells you to do

**For windows**-->There are some people who got detected flutter and dart plugins by the flutter doctor and few are not

I got this issue when I tried to install ...
I did everything like installed flutter and dart plugin still my flutter doctor haven't detected the plugins ...

**following steps worked for me**

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
flutter doctor -v
```

note :--- `flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"` should be example  `flutter config "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

above steps worked for me i hope it will helps you too :)

Answer (score 19):

change channel master to dev.
then upgrade.

```
flutter channel dev
flutter channel upgrade
```

try again

```
flutter doctor
```

Note: I think it's Android Studio 4.1  issue...

Answer (score 7):

Since you say you have flutter plugin installed in Android Studio, and if Android Studio correctly shows your installed plugin, there is no reason to believe any third-party tool reporting otherwise.

Also, this will not affect your flutter development and your IDE plugins will work as expected inside the IDE and flutter tool's commands work independent of the IDE in use.

Android Studio 4.1 apparently [changed its default plugin install path](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69514#issuecomment-720029228).

Related github issue: [[flutter_tools] IDE plugin validators should be deprecated #61246](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61246)

> Flutter does not directly use the IDE plugins, so doctor failing to detect them does not affect any behavior (it's just annoying).

Answer (score 4):

1. open terminal:
2. run> flutter channel dev
3. run> flutter channel upgrade

Answer (score 3):

open terminal:
Mac User:
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app

Comment: This is useful when flutter fails to find Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Flutter Plugin from Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Android Studio V 4.1?
With Android Studio V4.1 there is a problem.
Try to reinstall Android Studio but Version 4.0.1 and try it again, chances are this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android studio
2. Follow the Path **Configure > Plugins > marketplace > search Flutter & Dart > Install**
3. Restart IDE(Android studio)
4. Open Terminal and Export Flutter Path
5. and run **flutter doctor -v**

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading for an existing project:

Run

`git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

in your terminal.

The be sure to delete the *Flutter* folder in your App's root directory. Otherwise you will get over 50k errors popping up

Answer (score 0):

Check your flutter PATH

> `which flutter`

if you get `/path-to-flutter-sdk/bin//flutter` or similar you may have added an extra / in your $HOME/.rc_file. Remove the last '/', restart terminal and try again

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

`flutter channel dev`

`flutter doctor`