# Flutter and Dart plugin not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, plugins

I think that I have the same problem mentioned in this link [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37670) and both flutter and dart plugins are installed, **I tried to uninstall and install again the plugins** but flutter doctor gives me

```
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

Any Idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Try reinstall android studio,after updating android 4.1 there is problem arises for plugins@Malakmkd

Comment: Reinstall Flutter & Dart Plugin from Android Studio.

Comment: @Assassin okay will try it

Comment: @BholendraSingh I did it, not working

Comment: here is my answer please give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/64962784/12553303

Answer (score 2):

This happens with the new Android Studio Version 4.1.
It is working with Android Studio 4.0.1.

Comment: yes it suddenly happend with me, any idea how resolve it if the re-installation doesn't work?

Comment: To be honest not sure what it is then. Have you followed these: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor steps carefully?

Comment: Yes, I installed version 4.0.1 and it worked as before, I think yes there's an issue with 4.1, thanks!