# Flutter Doctor:Flutter and dart plugin not installed error,but plugins are installed(WINDOWS)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Both plugins are installed but cannot access the plugins in android studio shows following error even if it installed

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1082], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: try uninstall android studio and flutter plugin,restart your pc then install it again,in android 4.1 the plugins are breaking,there is lot of query about this,for some of them uninstalling and installing again worked,@Atharva Sonawane

Comment: here is my answer please give it a try --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64962784/12553303

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the upgrade to Flutter 1.22.2

See this issue : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986

... and the post on Google groups:

Hi,

Flutter 1.22.2 has been released to stable.  This is a hotfix release on the 1.22 branch and also includes a hotfixed Dart 2.10.2 version.  Changes for this build are listed below and are available on the Flutter Wiki here: Hotfixes to the Stable Channel.

This fixes the following issues:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67869 - Stylus tap gesture is improperly registered.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986 - Android Studio 4.1 not properly supported.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67213 - Webviews in hybrid composition can cause a crash.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67345 - VoiceOver accessibility issue with some pages.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66764 - Native webviews may not be properly disposed of in hybrid composition.

Thanks!

patrick, on behalf of the Flutter & Dart teams.

Answer (score -1):

open Plugins from settings in Android Studio, and search for Flutter and install it, it will also install dart plugin with it and then restart Android Studio

Answer (score -1):

Open Android Studio -> Go to Settings -> Go to Plugins and check that Dart and Flutter plugins are installed on Android studio
[image]