# The Flutter and Dart plugins not installed

Tags: flutter

[![Plugins installed][1]][1]
I had installed the plugins in android studio and add C:\flutter\bin to the system environment variables, but when I run the **flutter doctor** in the PowerShell, it showed the plugins not installed.
I'm using **Windows OS**.

````
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Downloading Material fonts...                                       0.5s
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                       0.0s
Downloading package sky_engine...                                   0.1s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                            1.0s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                    1.9s
Downloading windows-x64 tools...                                    2.2s
Downloading windows-x64/font-subset tools...                        0.1s
Downloading android-arm-profile/windows-x64 tools...                0.3s
Downloading android-arm-release/windows-x64 tools...                0.3s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/windows-x64 tools...              0.3s
Downloading android-arm64-release/windows-x64 tools...              0.3s
Downloading android-x64-profile/windows-x64 tools...                0.3s
Downloading android-x64-release/windows-x64 tools...                0.3s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KQHy.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

**By using these steps:**

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
flutter doctor -v
```

[Android Studio Dart And Flutter Plugin is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369971/android-studio-dart-and-flutter-plugin-is-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the **issue** :

**Step 1: (Accepting liscences)**

1.Open your terminal

2.run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

3.press `y` to accept every license.

**Step 2:(Flutter plugin)**

This is the last and final step !!!

Open android studio then on the configure screen select plugin from the bottom right corner, or by going into **File > Settings > Plugins and then search for Flutter in ‘Search in repositories’**

Search for `Flutter` on the marketplace , **install** and **restart** the IDE.
Do the same for **dart**.

Your error will be gone.

Comment: I don't see the  **Search in repositories** in my android studio, but I have installed and restarted the IDE but still plugins not installed.