# Flutter installation on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install flutter on Ubuntu 20.04. I am getting this issue on running flutter doctor

```
Android Studio
   ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
   ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

[screenshot of command " flutter doctor -v "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZxVO.png)

I have already downloaded flutter and dart in android studio
( [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apkf7.png) ) but I am still getting this issue.
Already tried
--android-sdk directory and
--android-studio-dir and update-alternatives --config java for jdk 8.

Comment: Have you tried restarting terminal and android studio after installation?

Comment: yes even restarted the pc

Comment: Is this the complete terminal message you get after running `flutter doctor`?

Comment: @ASADHAMEED https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZxVO.png

Comment: Try these solutions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor

Comment: If you have installed Android Studio for your user only, this error will appear. You will have to install it globally on your machine, like in the `/opt` folder. I personally have IntelliJ (which is basically Android Studio with less plugins) installed for my local user and I do get these errors but it doesn't affect my development. Hope this helps