# How to fix flutter plugin not installed while installing flutter in flutter doctor

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have installed flutter and I am using Android Studio for Android Virtual Device (AVD) and Visual Studio Code (VS Code) for installing dart and flutter extension. 
 On running **flutter doctor** in command prompt it is throwing error-

```
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

How can I solve this problem? TIA. 
[image]

Comment: I also had same issue after upgrading flutter, but when i ran the application, there was no error, try running the application.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the plugins,try run your app ,i have same issue shows  after running flutter doctor,but i have no problem to run my project without any problems@Abhinav

Comment: I've installed flutter and faced exactly same problem. I've also [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor) this but yet not able to install in Android Studio. But by following this I've able to install flutter plugin in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is just shown in flutter doctor, the application works fine even with it.