# Flutter is not being recognized on the machine

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I formatted my computer and installed windows 10 again because I wanted to play and Linux was having problems.
I am trying to install flutter and dart for application development, but he is accusing this error.

[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGbpQ.png)

I tested it before changing the flutter to beta and it recognized the flutter and dart plugins, however I want to leave it in the stable channel.

However, my code doesn't recognize it, I believe it is because of these errors with the flutter and dart plugins.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xqsr.png)

I already installed the plugins through android studio and also vscode.
I tried to uninstall and install again, restart the computer, set path ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor   

This might help you

Comment: I have already looked at this entire question and did everything it says, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it, I will leave here the solution for those who had the same problem as me.

I changed the channel to the Master and ran a flutter upgrade.
Now everything is running smoothly.
Maybe some bug with the stable channel, I can't say.

So:

1. Flutter channel master
2. Flutter upgrade

VOILÁ

[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCIgv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install flutter plugin in android studio properly? (Recheck in android studio.)

1. if yes then remove it and reinstall it.

if (1) not working then update your android studio.

2. **keep your flutter sdk in c drive**

if still flutter cannot trace plugin then set **flutter sdk** and **dart sdk** manually in android studio.

for dart
[image]

for flutter

[image]

Comment: 1. I did this, uninstalled and installed the plugins again in android studio.
2. My android studio is at version 4.1.1, the newest version.
3. I already made this configuration in android studio, it is the same as the example you sent.

The error continues.

Comment: I think you miss something. I suggest you forget everything then start from first. and try step by step. you can follow this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VxMWJV8Mm4&ab_channel=CodingCafe)

Comment: I followed all the steps you described above.

Comment: I followed all the steps in the video, my settings are exactly the same.