# Flutter doesn't detect android studio, its sdk, plugins and virtual device

Tags: android-studio, flutter

i'm trying to learn Flutter and so i followed the installation steps required for it.
[Unfortunately i have some dependencies error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCgHe.png) whenever i run `flutter doctor`

I checked Android studio and found out that the [sdk was successfully installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U1a0.png)

I tried to follow the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location) and [add the path in the environment variable](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/683824389334368297/783264846745042944/unknown.png).

I keep getting the same error and i start to run out of ideas as to how to install flutter.

Flutter error:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630], locale en-GB)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try to install flutter and dart plugin in android studiohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617408/how-to-install-plugin-in-android-studio  and try to locate sdk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739114/android-studio-sdk-location#:~:text=Mac%20users%20running%3A-,Open%20Android%20Studio,screen%20under%20%5BAndroid%20SDK%20Location%5D

Comment: Sorry i forgot to send the screenshot about the plugins. [I already installed those too](https://i.gyazo.com/6d23872c42abd60324b05faf519b02bf.png) as for the sdk it's [located here](https://i.gyazo.com/3761068878f7adb70e3d3aafe5c81f33.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio Version 4.1 is not compatible!
Flutter & Dart Plugins are working in 4.0.1 and might be working in 4.1.1 but 4.1 is broken. So downgrade Android Studio to 4.0.1 (works guaranteed) or try 4.1.1 (which might or might not work).

Comment: I downgraded to 4.0.1but still get the [same error](https://i.gyazo.com/743b5e8b1376945700484c0d6f215f1f.png)

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the Dart/Flutter Plugin? No idea why you can't find the Android SDK. Sounds basic but have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: The SDK issue has been fixed after restarting(no idea why it needed a restart since i closed every cmd and environment windows) .
Though [i still have the message](https://i.gyazo.com/ab9a7ad231148c3699333e22f04fd190.png) that states that the android studio isn't found and for some reason it thinks it's version 4.1 when it's version 4.0.1

Comment: Well you try to run flutter clean in the terminal and check if Android Studio 4.0.1 is recognized after that but I doubt it. You probably have to deinstall Android Studio and reinstall 4.0.1 :/ on the bright side your problem should be fixed then.

Comment: I manage to find the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747043/flutter-doctor-incorrectly-reporting-android-studio-flutter-plugin-not-instal) and it fix the issue for me! the dev branch works while the master one was broken.
Thanks a lot for the support help!